# how to check the text field value in workflow rule criteria which contain single quote

Tags: workflow

```
AND( 
ischanged(Private_case_comment_count__c ), ispickval(Department__c,"HR"), 
Queue_Name__c = 'Mother's Room', 
ISPICKVAL(Origin , 'Email'), 
BEGINS( OwnerId , "005"), 
OwnerId <> $User.Id 
)
```

How to check the Queue_Name__c text field value as "Mother's Room" which contain a single quote

Answer (score 1):

To include the string literal `Mother's Room` in the rule criterion for a workflow rule, you could use double quotes:

```
Queue_Name__c = "Mother's Room"
```